# Unable to enable Javascript in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to enabled javascript in Chrome. Option to enable/disable is coming as disabled (snapshot attached).

I tried installing different version also, but looks like versions are picking the same setting.

Anyone know how can I enable it via settings (some flag in preference directly), since button to enable it via UI is disabled itself. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed the manifest file inside

/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest

Searched for JavaScript and changed DefaultJavaScriptSettings. It works for now.